# Map text/plain multiline key=value http response to json and or c# object

Tags: c#, json, web, httpclient

I am hitting a 3rd party api and getting a plain text response in the body with the following format:

```
item[0].Name = name  
item[0].Type = type  
item[1].Name etc...
```

Is there a simple way of taking this and mapping it to an object or JSON in c#?

I've tried manipulating the string to replace "\n" with "," and "=" with ":"  and serializing it as a JSON object but didn't get anywhere with it. I also tried splitting the string and creating objects from it that way which worked but I need to hit a lot of endpoints from this api with varying results and it's not a very clean solution.

**Edit**

After reading the response content as a string the exact format of the response is
`item[0].Name=name\r\nitem[0].Type=type\r\nitem[1].Name=name\r\nitem[1].Type=type`

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Has the third party API documented their data format, and provided any information? Does the third party API perhaps allow for different return formats that you are able to choose by passing the right header?

Comment: The document just states depending on the endpoint it can come back as multiline plain text or JSON object but I have tried passing accept application/json and content-type application/json but it always come back the same way.

Comment: Can you please post precisely what is the plain text in a body? What you posted doesn' t look like a plain text to me.

Comment: I added an edit to show the exact format after reading the response.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it was tested in Visual Studio

```
static void Main()
{

var t = @"item[0].Name = name0
item[0].Type = type0
item[1].Name = name1
item[1].Type = type1";

    var ta = t.Split("\r\n");

List<NameType>  list = new List<NameType>();
for (var i = 0; i < ta.Length; i += 2)
{
var itemNameArr = ta[i].Split("=");
var itemTypeArr = ta[i + 1].Split("=");

if( itemNameArr[0].Substring(0,itemNameArr[0].IndexOf(".")) 
      != itemTypeArr[0].Substring(0,itemNameArr[0].IndexOf("."))) return //error ; 
        
    var itemName = itemNameArr[1].Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
    var itemType= itemTypeArr[1].Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty); 
    list.Add(new NameType { Name = itemName, Type = itemType });
}
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
}

public class NameType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

json

```
[
  {
    "Name": " name0",
    "Type": " type0"
  },
  {
    "Name": " name1",
    "Type": " type1"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was trying to do but cleaner, I am now thinking of using a regular expression to remove the item[0]. and populating an object with LINQ. If that doesn't work out though I will come back to this.

Comment: @McAuley I am sure you know that compiller converts a regular expression to string operations, and Linq to foreach.  I prefer to keep everytning under control, dont count on a smart compiler.